# Keep getting POST http://localhost:3001/subscribe 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, email

Im using React for client side and NodeJS for back end and MySQL for database. My goal is to create email subscription service on client side that when user inputs email and submits it back end inserts that email into database. Unfortunately for some reason i get this POST 500 Internal Server Error. I know when i get 500 error that API end point works but for some reason it doesnt post email into database.

NodeJS:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

/* Email Subscription for website owner! */

// MySQL credentials

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,
  user: "root",
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: "emailSubscriptions",
});

// API endpoint to handle email subscription
app.post("/subscribe", (req, res) => {
const email = req.body.email;

// Insert email address into MySQL database
const query = `INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ("${email}")`;
  db.query(query, [email], (error, results) => {
  console.log(query + email);
  if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
  });
```

ReactJS:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Subscribe() {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(email);
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/subscribe", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      alert("Successfully subscribed!");
      setEmail("");
    } else {
      alert("Failed to subscribe. Please try again later.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};


return (
    <section className="bg-subscribe-bg bg-cover bg-bottom bg-no-repeat p-[150px] h- 
     [80vh] flex flex-col items-start justify-center sm:p-[20px]">
        <div>
            <h2 className="text-slate-400 mb-[15px] text-4xl">Pridružite se našoj mail 
          list</h2>
            <p className="text-slate-400 mb-[70px] text-xl">Ne propustite najnovije 
             vijesti iz arhitekture i naših budućih projekata</p>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="flex w-[100%]">
                <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => 
                 setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Vaš email" className="h-[45px] 
                  w-[70%] border-[1px]"/>
                <button type="submit" className="h-[45px] bg-cyan-600 hover:bg-cyan-900 
                text-white w-[30%]">Pošalji</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    )
}
```

EDIT (FIXED): I was getting error errno: 1251, sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client. So i fixed my issue when i used mysql2 instead of just mysql, i used const mysql = require("mysql2") and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think error came from NodeJS code. You use template literals to insert the email value into the query. I suggest to use  placeholders instead. According to my opinion change the

```
const query = "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (?)";
db.query(query, [email], (error, results) => {
```

Comment: You need to show the request you are sending and a copy of the error message that you are receiving / logging from your application. I would also suggest that you start eliminating scenarios - i.e. make sure your API is working before you start introducing your front end code.

Comment: I've been getting errno: 1251, sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client so i changed to mysql2 in const mysql = require("mysql2") and now it works.